# WordPermalink not working after server tran

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I've transferred our website http://www.pacificluxuryliving.com from powweb to godaddy. It's a wordpress based website.
The problem is the pretty permalink is not working. It shows 404 error. Interestingly, If I add new post or new page, the permalink work. But all old permalinks not working. I can edit old pages and change the permalink (from edit page). If I change the old permalink to new one, then it also work.
I disabled pretty permalink + deleted .htaccess file. Then enabled pretty permalink from wp admin > settings > permalinks (it automatically restored .htaccess);
Tried many other ways, but nothing worked.

Thanks,
Farhad

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: Can you show us the contents of your .htaccess?

Comment: Hello Sheikh Heera and Beto Frega. I was new to Stackoverflow and didn't know how to get responses. So I didn't see your answers/comments till now. I solved this problem. But now I can't remember - what did I do. I appreciate your answers and comments.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following

- Do you have mod_rewrite enabled?
- Do you have any caching Plugins? If yes then disable them.
- Is FollowSymLinks option enabled?

Also post the contents of your .htaccess file and the pretty permalink format that you want to use.